# Design idea for implementing training project

Tags: salesforce-support

I have a design situation where fields and values as mentioned below,

```
Batch Type --> Course type --> Class Type --> Class
A -->  B --> C --> D
A -->  B --> C --> E
A -->  B --> C --> F
A -->  B --> C --> G
A -->  B --> C --> H
A -->  B --> C --> I
A -->  B --> C --> J
K -->  L --> M --> N
K -->  L --> M --> O
K -->  L --> M --> P
K -->  L --> M --> Q
K -->  L --> M --> R
K -->  L --> M --> S
K -->  L --> M --> T
```

I want a Contact to be assigned a Batch Type, Course Type & Class Type. Based on that would like to know what all Class value are possible for that.

Also, there must at least be a case a created for each class with status as "New". There may be additional new cases created for each of the Class.

I am planning to use a Product object to have the Batch Type, Course type, Class Type, and Class fields.  This would ensure to list out all the class that a contact must complete even without the case records. Is this a good choice?

Also, I want to report for each contact how many class has been assigned, how many are not started/new, in-progress and completed.

I am planning to create a report using the contact and product object. Any additional constructive suggestions please?

Also, its possible that an employee may be assigned to different Batch Type, Course Type & Class Type. Based on that new cases must be created for the corresponding classes.

I would like to retain the status of case classes for earlier batch type. What would be the best way to achieve it?

Comment: How are contact, case, product, order, order item and work order relation to each other in terms of data model?

How best can I use them for implementation?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. The format here is *specific* questions about implementation. Broad solicitations for suggestions tend to be off topic here.